# Какие ошибки не видит компилятор, но видит run-time?

Tags: c#, исключения, runtime

### Тест на собеседовании

Проходил онлайн-собеседование и был предложен тест:

> What is the result of the following code?

```
int a = 5;
object b = a;
double c = (double)b;
Console.Write(c);
```

- 5
- compilation error
- Neither answer is correct
- run-time error (exception)

---

### Мой ответ

*На сколько я понял это тест на глубокое понимание внутренней "кухни" C#.*

И дал я на него не правильный ответ - **5**.

После всего я набрал данный пример и вот что получилось во время выполнения:

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Вопрос

1. Компилятор ничего не подсветил. Почему так произошло? Что не может заранее увидеть компилятор, что может выявится во время run-time?
2. Правильно ли я понял, что в строке `object b = a;` переменная `b` динамически получает **ссылочный тип**, а на строке `double c = (double)b;` мы пытаемся преобразовать ссылочный тип в значимый (`(double)b`) и поэтому выскакивает исключение?

Comment: [Упаковка-преобразование и распаковка-преобразование](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

Comment: @Uranus: А зачем удалили ответ? Можно было просто исправить.

Comment: @VladD, он его кстати исправил, а только потом удалил зачем-то

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Никакой особой «внутренней кухни» тут нет.

Для начала, выражение `object b = a;`. Это *упаковка*. Согласно документации, упаковка всегда возможна и является неявным преобразованием. Поэтому компилятор не ругается на несоответствие типов, упаковка в `object` возможна всегда.

Теперь, выражение `double c = (double)b;`. Тип `b` — `object`, поэтому это выражение является *распаковкой* в значимый тип `double`. Смысл распаковки такой: если в `b` в самом деле упаковано значение **в точности** типа `double`, то оно оттуда берётся, иначе происходит исключение.

Компилятор не следит за тем, какой тип был ранее упакован в `b` (потому что в общем случае он не может этого сделать), так что он не знает, что в `b` реально `int`. Чего компилятор *не* делает, так это попытки достать `int` из `b`, и попытаться преобразовать его к `double`. Опять-таки потому, что он не умеет преобразовать во время выполнения *произвольный* значимый тип в другой значимый тип (а точный тип, лежащий в `b`, компилятор не знает).

В вашем случае в `b` оказывается упакованный `int`, так что происходит «законное» исключение.

Comment: а вот интересно, научить runtime преобразовать во время выполнения произвольный значимый тип в другой значимый тип, это непосильная задача?

Comment: @Murad: Хм, а как это сделать вообще? Вот у вас есть `DateTime` и `Point`, как преобразовать их друг в друга?

Comment: Элементарно же. Заполняем область памяти байтами насколько хватит, а там, как повезёт.

Comment: _Компилятор не следит за тем, какой тип был ранее упакован в b_. Выходит, что компилятор транслирует строчки кода `object b = a` и `double c = (double)b` в байт-код (для CLR) раздельно? Т.е. трансляция `double c = (double)b;` рассматривается вообще без какого-либо контекста?

Comment: @adamshakhabov явное приведение типов в качестве контекста использует программиста, который используя данную операцию подтверждает, что вся ответственность за последствия лежит на нем лично. =)

Comment: @adamshakhabov: Да. А как вы ему прикажете работать, если `b` передаётся снаружи, как входной параметр? Тип объекта — это по сути единственная информация, которую о нём знает компилятор. (Ну ещё он следит за наличием инициализации для reference type'ов.)

Answer (score 10):

[Boxing/Unboxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

```
int a = 5;
object b = a;
```

В CLR существует такое понятие как *boxing* — это преобразование value-of типа в ссылочный тип. Когда вы выполняете неявное преобразование в `System.Object` в этом примере, CLR создаст объект в куче и присвоит его полю значение `5`. Этот механизм существует по ряду причин, одна из которых, это утверждение что любой тип в CLR наследуется от `System.Object`

```
double c = (double) b;
```

Обратный процесс называется *unboxing* и одной из его особенностей является то, что упакованный тип должен быть распакован именно в тот тип, в который был упакован. В вашем примере, запакованный тип — `Int32`, значит именно в `Int32` он и должен быть распакован.

Если выполнить ваш пример и пропустить этап boxing/unboxing то всё было бы корректно:

```
int a = 5;
double c = (double) a;
```

Если выполнить требования CLR и распаковать тип в нужный, то дальнейшее преобразование тривиально:

```
int a = 5;
object b = a;
double c = (int) b;
```