# Конвертирование из object в long

Tags: c#

Что я делаю не так:

```
object j = 149800000;
long h = (long)j;
```

Нужно из `object` конвертировать в `long`, в примере выше выходит необработанное исключение типа `System.InvalidCastException`:

> Заданное приведение является недопустимым.

Если же в переменную `j` присвоить большое значение а-ля

```
object j = 111114082411778;
long h = (long)j;
```

то всё нормально. Также при простом присвоении переменной типа `long` маленького значения тоже все нормально. Я бы и использовал простой `Int32`, но вот значения у меня могут быть как маленькие, так и большие, и приходят они в `object`.

Comment: Вопрос в том, какого типа значение попало в объект. Оно должно быть строго типа `long`.

Comment: Дубликат? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/635993/10105

Comment: @VladD насколько мне известно, то long принимает значение от -9223372036854775808 до 9223372036854775807 тобишь, мое число, по идее, входит в этот диапазон и может восприниматься, как long

Comment: @Lolidze входит. А ещё оно входит в `int`. Поэтому компилятор справедливо считает, что негоже выделять 8 байтов там, где хватит 4. Попробуйте сделать `Console.WriteLine(j.GetType());` для первого числа - увидите `System.Int32` в консоли.

Comment: Есть, кстати, [статья](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/) по этому поводу.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Нужно в конец добавить суффикс L, так как `149800000` компилятор воспринимает как `int`.

```
object j = 149800000L;
long h = (long)j;
```

можно еще так

```
object j = 149800000;
long h = (long)(int)j;
```

Comment: проблема в том, что я не знаю, какое значение придет в object, оно может быть, как маленьким, тогда такой подход long h = (long)(int)j; сработает, так и большим, тогда long h = (long)(int)j; не сработает

Comment: Но вариант с добавлением L в конец мне подходит, вроде бы, спасибо

Comment: @Lolidze еще можно использовать Convert.ToInt64(i), и тогда уже не надо беспокоиться что лежит в  object, главное чтоб число было.

Comment: @Lolidze да, второй вариант крайне сомнительный. Тут либо в `j` всегда по факту передавать `long`, либо использовать метод `Convert.ToInt64`.

Comment: большое всем спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать [`Int64.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zc2x2b1h(v=vs.110).aspx) - преобразует строковое представление числа в эквивалентное ему 64-битовое целое число со знаком. Возвращает значение, указывающее, успешно ли выполнено преобразование. Вот и пример преобразования:

```
object j = 149800000;
long number;
bool result = Int64.TryParse(j.ToString(), out number);
if (result)
{
    // успешно преобразовали. В number - результат
}
else
{
    // что-то пошло не так
}
```

Или же использовать [`Convert.ToInt64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0zahhahw(v=vs.110).aspx) - преобразует заданное строковое представление числа в эквивалентное 64-битовое целое число со знаком. Немного менее безопасный вариант преобразования:

```
object j = 149800000;
long result = Convert.ToInt64(j);
```

Если тут не удастся преобразовать - словим исключение. Метод [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает строковое представление текущего объекта, данный метод есть у всех объектов, что упрощает работу.